# Magento 2 How to create admin grid using Block(.php) file?

Tags: magento2, blocks, grid

How can we create admin grid by using Block (.php) file?
Everytime when I tried to create block via .php file, I got stuck in between and didn't find any solution.

This time I am successful in this.

So posting a question here with answer. Hope it helps you..!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **1)** app/code/[Vendor_Name]/[Namespace]/registration.php :

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    '[Vendor_Name]_[Namespace]',
    __DIR__
);
```

> **2)** app/code/[Vendor_Name]/[Namespace]/etc/module.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="[Vendor_Name]_[Namespace]" setup_version="1.0.0" />
</config>
```

> **3)** app/code/[Vendor_Name]/[Namespace]/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="[myurl]" frontName="[myurl]">
            <module name="[Vendor_Name]_[Namespace]" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

> **4)** app/code/[Vendor_Name]/[Namespace]/etc/adminhtml/menu.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="[Vendor_Name]_[Namespace]::myadmingrid" title="My admin grid" module="[Vendor_Name]_[Namespace]" sortOrder="50" parent="Magento_Sales::sales" action="[myurl]/index/index" resource="[Vendor_Name]_[Namespace]::myadmingrid"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

> **5)** app/code/[Vendor_Name]/[Namespace]/view/adminhtml/layout/[myurl]_index_index.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="[Vendor_Name]\[Namespace]\Block\Adminhtml\MyGrid" name="my_admin_grid"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="admin.myadmingrid.grid"></referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> **6)** app/code/[Vendor_Name]/[Namespace]/view/adminhtml/templates/grid.phtml :

```
<?php echo $block->getGridHtml() ?>
```

> **7)** app/code/[Vendor_Name]/[Namespace]/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index.php :

```
<?php

   namespace [Vendor_Name]\[Namespace]\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

   use Magento\Backend\App\Action;

   class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action{

       /**
        * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
        */
       private $resultPageFactory;

       /**
        * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
        * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
        */
       public function __construct(
           \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
           \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
       ) {
           parent::__construct($context);
           $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
       }

       public function execute(){
           $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
           $resultPage->setActiveMenu('[Vendor_Name]_[Namespace]::myadmingrid');
           $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('My Admin Grid'));
           return $resultPage;
       }
   }
```

> **8)** app/code/[Vendor_Name]/[Namespace]/Block/Adminhtml/MyGrid.php :

```
<?php

namespace [Vendor_Name]\[Namespace]\Block\Adminhtml;

class MyGrid extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Container
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_template = 'grid.phtml';

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context,array $data = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare button and grid
     *
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product
     */
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $this->setChild(
            'grid',
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('[Vendor_Name]\[Namespace]\Block\Adminhtml\MyGrid\Grid', 'admin.myadmingrid.grid')
        );
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
    /**
     * Render grid
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getGridHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('grid');
    }

}
```

> **9)** app/code/[Vendor_Name]/[Namespace]/Block/Adminhtml/MyGrid/Grid.php :

```
<?php
namespace [Vendor_Name]\[Namespace]\Block\Adminhtml\MyGrid;

class Grid extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager
     */
    protected $moduleManager;

    protected $itemFactory;


    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager
     * @param array $data
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ItemFactory $itemFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->itemFactory = $itemFactory;
        $this->moduleManager = $moduleManager;
        parent::__construct($context, $backendHelper, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setId('postGrid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('created_at');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
        $this->setUseAjax(false);
        $this->setVarNameFilter('post_filter');
    }

    /**
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        //You can select your custom data here
        $collection = $this->itemFactory->create()->getCollection();

        $collection->getSelect()
                ->join(array('sales_order'), 'main_table.order_id= sales_order.entity_id',array('orderstatus' => 'sales_order.status', 'customer_id' => 'sales_order.customer_id', 'increment_id' => 'sales_order.increment_id'))
                ->join(array('customer_entity'), 'sales_order.customer_id= customer_entity.entity_id',array('firstname' => 'customer_entity.firstname', 'lastname' => 'customer_entity.lastname'))
                ->join(array('store'), 'main_table.store_id= store.store_id',array('store' => 'store.name'))
                ->where('order_item_serialcode.status=1');

        $collection->addExpressionFieldToSelect(
                            'fullname',
                            'CONCAT({{customer_firstname}}, \' \', {{customer_lastname}})',
                            array('customer_firstname' => 'firstname', 
                                    'customer_lastname' => 'lastname')
                            );

        $this->setCollection($collection);

        parent::_prepareCollection();

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn(
         'store',
         [
             'header' => __('Store'),
             'index' => 'store',
         ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
         'fullname',
         [
             'header' => __('Customer'),
             'index' => 'fullname',
         ]
        );
        // If you want to export data
        $this->addExportType($this->getUrl('[myurl]/index/exportCsv', ['_current' => true]),__('CSV'));
        $this->addExportType($this->getUrl('[myurl]/index/exportExcel', ['_current' => true]),__('Excel XML'));

        $block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('grid.bottom.links');
        if ($block) {
            $this->setChild('grid.bottom.links', $block);
        }

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('[myurl]/index/index', ['_current' => true]);
    }

    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
        return '#';
    }          
}
```

> **10)** app/code/[Vendor_Name]/[Namespace]/view/adminhtml/layouot/[myurl]_index_exportcsv.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="[myurl]_index_grid"/>
</page>
```

> **11)** app/code/[Vendor_Name]/[Namespace]/view/adminhtml/layouot/[myurl]_index_exportexcel.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="[myurl]_index_grid"/>
</page>
```

> **12)** app/code/[Vendor_Name]/[Namespace]/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/ExportCsv.php :

```
<?php

namespace [Vendor_Name]\[Namespace]\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory;

class ExportCsv extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $_fileFactory;

    public function execute()
    {
        $this->_view->loadLayout(false);

        $fileName = 'mygridreport.csv';

        $exportBlock = $this->_view->getLayout()->createBlock('[Vendor_Name]\[Namespace]\Block\Adminhtml\Report\Grid');

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

        $this->_fileFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory');

        return $this->_fileFactory->create(
            $fileName,
            $exportBlock->getCsvFile(),
            DirectoryList::VAR_DIR
        );
    }
}
```

> **12)** app/code/[Vendor_Name]/[Namespace]/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/ExportExcel.php :

```
<?php

namespace [Vendor_Name]\[Namespace]\Controller\Adminhtml\Report;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory;

class ExportExcel extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $_fileFactory;

    public function execute()
    {
        $this->_view->loadLayout(false);

        $fileName = 'mygridexport.xml';

        $exportBlock = $this->_view->getLayout()->createBlock('[Vendor_Name]\[Namespace]\Block\Adminhtml\Report\Grid');

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

        $this->_fileFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory');


        return $this->_fileFactory->create(
            $fileName,
            $exportBlock->getExcelFile(),
            DirectoryList::VAR_DIR
        );
    }
}
```